# unexpected token < in json at position 0 python, selenium

Tags: python, json, selenium, authentication, autologin

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


username = 'xxxxxxxx'
password = 'xxxx'

url = 'https://betfury.io/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get(url)

time.sleep(10)
#log poga
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[3]/div/div/nav/div[2]/div/button[1]').click()
time.sleep(10)

# Email input
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/div/input').send_keys(username)
#pass input
#/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/div/input
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/div/input').send_keys(password)

#press login button
loginbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/form/button')
loginbutton.click()
```

and i get a erorr like this - unexpected token < in json at position 0
i use python 3.9 code run into pycharm, use selenium webdriver - goglechromedriver
please help me out what i do wrong...

if i open google chrome driver and try manualy login, its the same error, in my orginal chrome its go, and dont have error...

Comment: What do you mean by `if i open google chrome driver and try manualy login, its the same error`? Are you talking about debugging run with this code or a regular, manually open a Chrome browser?

Comment: in normal crome all go,, but in cromedrive with script is not going... its show json error

Comment: That happens when cloudflare sends a 403 document instead of whatever json the page expected. In other words they stopped you because you're a bot.

Comment: how can change it? how make it to run?